# CloudfFont GetObjectRequest equivalent to download files from S3

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am revising an application to use a private CloudFront rather than straight from S3.

I have been able to create signed URLs and populate picturboxes as needed.

I am unable to find the CloudFront equivalent of the GetObjectRequest...

```
for (int num = 1; num < 16; num++)
{

    GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest
    {
        BucketName = ContainerName,
        Key = tempDownload + @"/" + num + ".jpg"
    };

    try
    {
        //Issue request and remember to dispose of the response
        using (GetObjectResponse response = s3Client.GetObject(request))
        {
          string dest = Path.Combine(newFileFolder, tempDownload + num + ".jpg");
            if (!File.Exists(dest))
            {
                response.WriteResponseStreamToFile(dest);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to download files through Cloudfront onto the application user's hard drive.

Comment: Why did you create Signed URL's and what you did with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CloudFront does not have an equivalent to `GetObject`. CloudFront is designed to pull data through the HTTP/HTTPS protocols.

If the files that you want to download to your user's computer are public, then you can simply access them through the CloudFront distributions http/https URL.

If the files that you want to download is private, then you'll need to setup an Origin Access Identity to [Serve Private Content](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html) or use [Pre-signed URLs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html) through your CloudFront distributions http/https URL.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I have already created Pre-signed URLs which are working when populating PictureBoxes in my application.  I am using the Cloudberry Application which has helped a lot.         What I am looking for is the code that gets the S3 file through the signed URL request of CloudFront and saved onto the user's hard drive?

Comment: There is sample C# code to generate a CloudFront pre-signed URL in the links I provided. With that URL, you won't use the AWS SDK to download the files. Instead, you'll use C#'s `HttpClient` (for example) to download the file as a standard URL.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  This was just the help I needed.